# AngularJS 10 $digest() iterations reached when generating random values

Tags: angularjs

I've got a directive that builds a list and I paint each item with a different color on the fly like:

```
$scope.color = function () {
    var letters = '012345'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 5)];
    letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
};
```

then I call it in the template like:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list">
   <a ng-style="{ background: color() }">{{item.acronym}}</a>
</li>
```

but when the template compiles i get this:

```
 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
 Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["{ background: color() }; newVal: {\"background\":\"#455116\"}; oldVal: {\"background\":\"#2B1EDC\"}"],["{ background: color()...<omitted>...5D
```

Obviosuly $digest is in a loop but why would my random color be causing this to do this and how do you address something like this outside of assigning the color to the object and referencing it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @doodeec suggested, I redid the `color` fn to pass the item iterating over like:

```
 <a ng-style="{ background: color(item) }">{{item.acronym}}</a>
```

and in the `color` fn I set it or said if it already has it return it instead...

```
$scope.color = function (item) {
    if (item.color) {
        return item.color;
    }

    var letters = '012345'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 5)];
    letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }

    // assign the color so it doesn't freak out
    item.color = color;

    return color;
};
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, it works like a charm.  Much nicer than iterating on creation and assigning imo.

Answer (score 5):

It's because the `color` function gets called in every digest cycle and in every function call it's generating different color... so it's changing multiple times in a second

Comment: you just generate the color once and you don't use the function expression inside the template... or basically make the function return always the same string for a single item